# Cambiar el color del texto flotante en un TextInputLayout

Tags: android

Mi objetivo es cambiar el color del texto flotante cuando este campo pierda el foco, explico:
Tengo una pantalla de login, en la cual el fondo es de color rojo, por lo tanto el objetivo es que el texto sea de color blanco para evitar que se pierda, el problema es que cuando este campo tiene texto y pierde el foco, cambia a el color primario

Elementos sin foco:
[image: Widgets en reposo]

En el primer elemento ya ingresé información y el foco lo tiene el segundo widget, y se aprecia el cambio de color.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Elemento XML:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="prueba"
                app:hintTextAppearance="@style/test_appearance">

                <EditText
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:padding="8dp"
                    android:textColor="@color/color.black"
                    android:background="@color/color.white"/>
            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Este es el estilo aplicado al Widget:

```
<style name="test_appearance" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/color.white</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">14sp</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

Cuando la vista pierde el foco se muestra el "hint" entonces en tu `style`  puedes agregar `android:textColorHint`:

```
 <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/<colo></item>
```

y para otros estados, también :

```
<item name="colorAccent">@color/<colo></item>
<item name="colorControlNormal">@color/<colo></item>
<item name="colorControlActivated">@color/<colo></item>
```

Comment: Agregué las propiedades que mencionas y no me funcionó, no cambio nada.

Answer (score 1):

Una forma de hacerlo es usar el siguiente estilo en el AppTheme:

```
<item name="colorControlActivated">@color/TU_COLOR</item>
```

Me cuentas si te funciona.

Comment: No me funcionó, solo pinta el color del cursor.

Comment: Pon la línea en tu AppTheme y en tu TextInputLayout widget remueve la propiedad app:hintTextAppearance. Y en el mismo app theme, empieza a jugar con las propiedades android:textColorHint y colorControlNormal para terminar de configurar tus estilos. Me cuentas que sucede.